# how to remove element { background color in css using browser extension?

Tags: html, css

How to remove the element background color using browser extension for a online website? I want to remove this color for add this website in OBS?
I've tried this:

```css
    main-content wf100 {
        background-color: transparent;  
    }


    .main-content .wf100 {
        background: transparent;    
    }

    #main-content .wf100 {
        background: transparent;    
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Try using `!Important` if it's a js generated style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main-content and wf100 are two classes for the same element. So, the code will be like this--

```
.main-content.wf100{
   background: transparent; 
}
```

if this does not work, use this ***!important*** flag on CSS value.

**Example--**

```
.main-content.wf100{
   background: transparent !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use **!important** in end of your code

Example:

```css
.main-content.wf100 {
    background: transparent !important;    
}
```

REF:
https://www.w3schools.com/css//css_important.asp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just write like this:

```
.main-content {
  background-color: transparent;  
}
```

if didn't work add !important after transparent

Answer (score 0):

If there are two or more CSS rules that point to the same element, the selector with the highest specificity value will "win", and its style declaration will be applied to that HTML element.

```
Inline Styles                               - 1000
ID selectors                                -  100
Classes, Attributes and Pseudo-classes      -   10
Elements and Pseudo-elements                -    1
```

So you can use !important for your CSS code.

```
.main-content.wf100 {
    background: transparent;    
}
```

The correct way to do this is to delete the inline css.

Answer (score 0):

First, none of your selectors are applied. The first and third one aren't because `main-content` is a class, so you have to use `.main-content`.

The second one isn't applyed to your element because you added a space between `.main-content` and `.wf100` wich means :
*element with `wf100` class inside a `main-content` element*.

Without the the space (`.main-content.wf100`) you specify :
*elements with `main-content` and `wf100` classes*.

Now your selector is correct, it still doesn't work. Why ? because inline css has the highest priority after `!important` property that you need to use here.

Because `!important` has the highest priority, you can apply it to `.main-content.wf100` but also `.main-content` or `.wf100`.

```css
/* wrong selector */
.main-content .wf100{
  background-color:green;
}
/* correct selector, but not enough priority */
.main-content.wf100{
  background-color:green;
}
.main-content.second-content{
  background-color:orange!important;
}
.another-content{
  background-color:yellow!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content wf100 "style="background-color:#172132;color:white;">wf100</div>
<br>
<div class="main-content second-content" style="background-color:red;">second content</div>
<br>
<div class="main-content another-content" style="background-color:red;">another content</div>
<br>
<div class="another-content" style="background-color:red;">another content without .main-content</div>
```